# Creating a link to logout for JSP

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, servlets, forms-authentication

when a user logins to my application, he submits a form to be processed through the Servlet. The servlet creates a session for the user. How would I create a link so the user can logout? I cannot seem to directly link to a Servlet. How would I delete the session and link back to the homepage?

Here is a way that I could do it, but it doesn't seem "right".
I could link back to the index.jsp?logout=true. My index.jsp will see if logout is true and delete the sessions.

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write a servlet mapped to `/logout` which then executes something like this in `doGet`:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session != null)
    session.invalidate();
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

It wont matter if the user has a session or not, they will ultimately be redirected to `index.jsp`.

Comment: I tried that, but I get a 404 error. My servlet is mapped correctly in web.xml, and my link goes to that servlet.

Comment: Then the URL is simply wrong :) Does it work when you enter it plain in browser address bar? Did you take the context path into account? Do you understand how relative URLs work?

Answer (score 4):

I found it easiest to do this:

```
<form method="link" action="logout.jsp">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout"/>
</form>
```

without logout.jsp having this:

```
<%
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect("startpage.html");
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do that is make a link of logout like this..

```
<a href="logout.jsp">LogOut</a>
```

And in the "logout.jsp" write below code

```
<%
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

logout is not too serious. you can have a simple /logout.jsp just to end session.

Answer (score 0):

Based on cdietschrun's answer, I've made it even more compact:

```
<%
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
%>
```